# Cross product between a vector and a 2nd order tensor

Tags: tensors, cross-product

I have been searching for quite a long time, and haven't been able to find any good reference about the cross product between a vector and a tensor:
$$ \vec{a} \times \underline{T}= \begin{pmatrix}a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3}\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}T_{11} & T_{12} & T_{13} \\T_{21} & T_{22} & T_{23}  \\ T_{31} & T_{32} & T_{33} \end{pmatrix}= \quad?$$
I think that I have to take the cross product between $\vec{a}$ and each column of $\underline{T}$ to construct the result, but I would like to be sure. I would also like to know a reference about that.
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure what you're writing is correct ? I mean, what is the definition of the cross product ? Did'nt you talk about the wedge product instead ?

Comment: My goal is to calculate a torque from a force using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque, so I think this is the usual cross product. My question here is related to this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303051/divergence-theorem-for-a-second-order-tensor

Comment: @lambertmular Force is a vector (sort-of) as is $\overline{r}$. So I don't see why you need a vector cross tensor product for torque, but my answer shows how to define one anyway.

Comment: I am using the Maxwell stress tensor to calculate the force, so in principle the force is a divergence of a tensor (i.e. a vector). However If I want to integrate by part I need to know the cross product of a vector with a tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly define cross products of vectors and 2nd order tensors in Euclidean 3-space.

For example, introduce a cartesian basis, so $\overline{a} \times \overline{T}$ is
$$
\overline{a} \times \overline{T} = (a_i \hat{e}^i) \times (T_{pq} \hat{e}^p\otimes \hat {e}^q) \\
=a_i T_{pq} (\hat{e}^i \times \hat{e}^p) \otimes \hat{e}^q
$$
where $\otimes$ is the tensor product.
If the second step seems unfamiliar, think about what you would do with a dot product $\overline{a} \cdot (\overline{b} \otimes \overline{c})$.

Now we rewrite the cross product itself.

$$
\overline{a} \times \overline{T}\\
=a_i T_{pq} (\epsilon_{lmn} \, e^i_m \, e^p_n \, \hat{e}^l) \otimes \hat {e}^q \\
=a_i T_{pq} \epsilon_{lmn} \, \delta_{im} \, \delta_{pn} \, (\hat{e}^l \otimes \hat {e}^q) \\
=\epsilon_{lip} \, a_i T_{pq} \, (\hat{e}^l \otimes \hat {e}^q) \\
$$
which returns an object with 2 free indices.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any book where I can find this? Maybe you know also how to do http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303051/divergence-theorem-for-a-second-order-tensor

Comment: @lambertmular Try the book by Knowles. http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Vector-Spaces-Cartesian-Tensors/dp/0195112547

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how $(a_i \hat{e}^i) \times (T_{pq} \hat{e}^p\otimes \hat {e}^q) = a_i T_{pq} (\hat{e}^i \times \hat{e}^p) \otimes \hat{e}^q$