# Mixed product of second-order tensors and vectors

Tags: inner-products, tensors, cross-product, continuum-theory

I was studying the angular momentum equation in the continuum case and I encountered this identity. I am not sure how the identity is derived. Could some one supply more details and intermediate step?
$$\int_s -\vec{n}\cdot(\underline{\sigma}\times\vec{r})dS=\int_s -\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}\times\vec{r}dS = \int_s \vec{r}\times\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}dS$$ where $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{r}$ are first-order tensors (vectors) and $\underline{\sigma}$ is a second-order tensor.

Comment: What is the cross product of a tensor and a vector?

Comment: @VincenzoTibullo You can have a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307835/cross-product-between-a-vector-and-a-2nd-order-tensor

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer. Basically, there is no order in the operation, thus one can see the dot product as a single object. The anticommutative property odds. Calling $\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}=\vec{a}$ then: $$ 
-\vec{a}\times\vec{r}=\vec{r}\times\vec{a}$$