# What is the definition of $\nabla \cdot(\vec{x}\times\textbf{T})$?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors, cross-product

Consider a vector $\vec{x}$ in three dimensions and $3\times 3$ second rank symmetric tensor $\textbf{T}$.

What is the definition of $\nabla \cdot(\vec{x}\times\textbf{T})$?

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308039/92915), I expect that to be $\textbf{e}_i \partial_l\left(\varepsilon_{ljk} x_j T_{ki}\right)$, because $$(\vec{x} \times \textbf{T})_{li} = \varepsilon_{ljk} x_j T_{ki},\, \text{and }\, \,\nabla \cdot (\vec{x}\times\textbf{T}) = \textbf{e}_i \partial_l (\vec{x} \times \textbf{T})_{li}.$$

However, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308157/92915) (between 5th and 6th line of the first calculation), it is written to be equal to $\mathbf{e}_i\partial_l(\varepsilon_{ijk}x_jT_{kl})$.

Am I missing something?